# MS ACCESS AVOIDING NOT IN

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010

I want to obtain the distinct value of Assets for FileID 6 which are not linked to any other FileID. I.e. a FileID can be linked to the same Asset.

I have used the following but it is way way to slow. Is there another way I can do this such as a Left Outer Join??? Appreciate any assistance as this is driving me crazy now.

```
Select distinct AssetName from Asset 
where FileID=6 and AssetName not in 
    (select AssetName from Asset where FileID <> 6)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT AssetName from 
    (SELECT AssetName, MAX(FileID) AS FileID from Asset 
    WHERE COUNT(FileID) = 1 GROUP BY AssetName)
WHERE FileID=6
```

I think this is what you want, first you select only those assets that have 1 FileID attached, then query assets with FileID=6.

Comment: I tried this and i was getting a circular error of some kind for FileID. Thanks anyway for your help. Another solution worked a treat!

Comment: @Vesper, error could be because you don't alias the nested query? Don't use access so might be talking nonsense.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should be joining on AssetName:

```
select distinct AssetName 
from Asset as a1
where FileID=6 
and   0 = (
  select count(*) 
  from Asset as a2 
  where FileID <> 6 and a1.AssetName = a2.AssetName
)
```

*Note:* I don't have Access, so it hasn't been tested. Indexes on both column would aid performance.